# can't get permission from my custom visual to access MediaDevice audio

Tags: powerbi

according to the [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Custom-Visual-Using-Javascript-Promises-in-Internet-Explorer-11/td-p/449795)

Power BI creates a copy of window object to isolate PBI code from Custom Visual's code.
but what if I want to record audio from my chrome

i am trying to record audio from my custom visual using javascript or jquery

```
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true }).then(suc => { console.log("suc"); }).catch(err => { console.log(err, "err"); });
```

i expect that the chrome will ask me about the permission for using microphone

but i found it block me and i think this happen because isolated scope
and i found error

```
    DOMException err
```

Comment: the console output is barely telling ...try `console.log(err.message);`

Comment: the error is `Invalid security origin`